# Mysql Workbench SELECT returns 0 rows without error

Tags: mysql, database, workbench

[no rows returned picture, me sql code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4eUL.png)

[insertions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4soMs.png)

I made the insertions, applied the changes. 
here's a script:

```
-- Table `db`.`TrainIn`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `db`.`TrainIn` (
  `TrNumInRec` INT NOT NULL,
  `DateIn` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `TrNum` INT NULL,
  `WayInNum` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`TrNumInRec`),
  INDEX `WayInNum_idx` (`WayInNum` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `WayInNum`
    FOREIGN KEY (`WayInNum`)
    REFERENCES `db`.`Towns` (`TownName`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: Depending on the value of `lower_case_table_names` there could be two tables with the same name but not the same `Case`. if the value = 0 then `TrainIn  != trainin`

Comment: I have checked, there are no same names. even with changing 'trainin'->'TrainIn' nothing changed @PeterM